# MySql INNER JOIN results in "weird" Array

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm not that good in advanced MySql and tried to join multiple tables and drop the results into a single PHP-Array.

```
SELECT * FROM AAA
        INNER JOIN BBB ON AAA.Aufg_id = BBB.Aufg_id
        INNER JOIN CCC ON AAA.SchuelerNr = CCC.schuelernr AND AAA.Schulnummer = CCC.schulnummer AND AAA.Klasse = CCC.klasse
        WHERE AAA.Schulnummer='$x' AND AAA.Klasse='$y' AND AAA.SchuelerNr='$z'
```

The result is dropped into a

```
mysqli_fetch_all($mysqli_result, MYSQLI_BOTH);
```

therefore I'm able to get the values associative or by number for iterating through a loop.
Almost everything worked fine, except of two values that were not supposed to be there:

```
[0] => DEMO11
        [sn] => DEMO11
        [1] => 2014-03-31 10:05:14
        [zt] => 2014-03-31 11:47:45
        [2] => 8a_D1
        [kl] => 8a_D1
        [3] => 4
        [snr] => 4
        [4] => 1
        [Aufg_id] => 1
        [5] => f
        [erg] => f
        [6] => 1   <<<< WHERE DOES THIS COME FROM?
        [7] => 1
        [th] => 1
        [8] => Deu
        [fac] => Deu
```

The value is increasing by one every row. Its right there between the tables AAA and BBB, without any associative key.

At the very end of every row, there is a even more irritating value representing a datetime from one of the other columns:

```
[43] => 8
[NA_Eng] => 8
[44] => 4
[NA_Fra] => 4
[45] => 2014-03-31 11:47:45 <<<<<< ???
```

**QUESTION:**
Where do those values come from? How can I get rid of them??

Comment: **Name your columns in the SELECT instead of using `*`.**

Comment: We'd have to know more about your schema to be able to tell you where that value is coming from, though I agree with @Sebas that you should be specifying the columns you want to return rather than using `SELECT *`

Comment: Of course I could limit the output by specifying the columns, but that would not solve the problem in the first place. I thought those values are originating from one terrible sql-mistake I made.
@brian: I'm afraid I can't put more of the database-structure online, because it's part of a real project :(

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
mysqli_fetch_all($mysqli_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

This way, you'll not get the numeric keys in your results.

See [MySQLi predefined constants](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php).

Comment: It seems like OP wants to have both string and numeric keys.